# Manually purging audit logs in AWS RDS MySQL instances

Tags: mysql, plugins, mariadb, amazon-rds, audit

I have recently enabled the MariaDB Audit Plugin on my MySQL RDS instance, and set up to have 1GB files and 100 files in rotation:

```
SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATE_SIZE=1000000000
SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS=100
```

All worked well, and files started accumulating with the following naming convention (notice the 3-digit format):

```
audit/server_audit.log.001
audit/server_audit.log.002
...
audit/server_audit.log.099
```

I then realised that I do not want to allocate 100GB of storage for audit logs, and updated the file in rotation option to 60 - hoping that around 40 files will be deleted. I was surprised to see that not only files were not deleted, but an additional set of files has now been created with a 2-digit format:

```
audit/server_audit.log.01
audit/server_audit.log.02
...
```

So it seems that I'm now stuck with 100GB of audit files that will not be purged.

Can anyone advise on how to force this purge, or manually remove unnecessary files when working woth an RDS instance?

Comment: any updates? I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @UsmanKhan I think I changed the file size (`SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATE_SIZE`) to a minimum in order to free up space. Once my files were all down to a minimal size I adjusted the number of files (`SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS`) to 10 in my case. That did the trick.

Comment: Changing the parameters inside the current option group will not delete the old audit files that were created by another audit group. You have to manually change the option group to delete previous audit log files created by previous option group

Answer (score 1):

The proper method to fix this issue is to change the Option Group to default. This will remove all 2-letter audit log files as well as 3-letter audit log files. Please make sure to export the log files into cloudwatch or s3 if you need them. When you change the option group to default, it instantly deletes all audit log files. After deletion, you can then change the option group back to what it was before and it will continue logging.